# Is there online markdown editor with buttons

Tags: markdown, wysiwyg

I am looking for `wysiwyg` markdown editor with livepreview .

I have this list http://mashable.com/2013/06/24/markdown-tools/

But here none has buttons in it. I mean . there i ahve to type the syntax like `##` for `heading and ,

````
``` code ```
````

for code.

What i am looking for is buttons toolbar where its written code and when i click on that the corresponding code gets wrapped . Like we do for html editors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to try [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/). It is a **wysiwyg** editor that includes **toolbar buttons** along with a host of other features to help you write code in **Markdown**.